# How do I select DOM elements being created in a Marionette ItemView?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have an item view that looks like this:

```
MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#static-template"

  onRender: function() {
    console.log($('#static-template').val())
  }
});
```

I want to use jQuery to select the `#static-template` element, but I am unable to do. How can I select this element with jQuery inside a `Marionette.ItemView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this.$el`.
In your case, `this.$el.attr("value");`